# Where is this shortcut coming from?

Tags: vim

I am writing a report on robot wars (as funny as it sounds).

One major section in my report is on EMP Cannons.  Whenever I type EMP I get this:

```
\begin{minipage}[]{<+width+>}
    <++>
\end{minipage}<++>
```

I am using macvim with some latex attachement.  Does anyone know how I can figure out where this is coming from and disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a vim `latex-suite` macro, the official way to disable these is described here
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html#latex-macros

However I had trouble getting those instructions to work in the past.
Eventually I created a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex/afterls.vim`
and added the line 
`call IMAP('EMP', 'EMP', 'tex')`
which just expands EMP to EMP.

This is a very silly way to do it so I am looking forward to seeing the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This found it:

```
% pwd
/Users/jsummers/.vim
% grep -r EMP .
./ftplugin/latex-suite/wizardfuncs.vim:\."\n EFL   ".g:Tex_Leader2."fl   flushleft           EMP   ".g:Tex_Leader2."mp   minipage"
%
```